# Phone based Checkout

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Can anyone recommends any extension which converts the checkout from email to phone OR what the possibilites of customizing the checkout to remove the email/password field.

I know the limitations of magento but need to validate if there is any possibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Please review the following extensions. They may meet your needs:**

**Extension 1:**

https://store.webkul.com/magento2-phone-number-login.html

**Extension 2:**

https://store.doyenhub.com/customer-login-and-register-with-mobile-number

**Extension 3:**

https://magecomp.com/magento-2-mobile-otp-login.html